# Haskell condition in a map function

Tags: haskell, dictionary

Is it possible to have a condition in a map function?

For example :

```
map (> 0 < 100 )[1..10]
```

If it's not possible, how could one achieve this?

Comment: What would you expect to be the value of that form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite like that, I presume you are trying to get a boolean indicating whether the value is greater than 0 and less than 100?  You have several options:

You can name a function

```
condition :: Int -> Bool
condition x = x > 0 && x < 100
map condition [1..10]
```

You can use a lambda

```
map (\x -> x > 0 && x < 100) [1..10]
```

You can use `Data.Ix` and the `inRange` function

```
import Data.Ix

-- inRange is inclusive.
map (inRange (1,99)) [1..10]
```

Comment: inRange only validates upperBound ? :-S

Comment: inRage is the values between two givens (so between 1 and 99 inclusive).  I just thought that simplified the >0 && <100 logic

Comment: actually i solved problem by writing my own inRange function ;-) working fine !

Answer (score 7):

A good way to express multiple filter conditions are for comprehensions, e.g.

```
[k | k <- [1..10], k > 2, k < 7]
```

You can avoid the lambda expression as well using `Applicative`, which allows to "feed" a single argument to several functions:

```
import Control.Applicative

filter ((&&) <$> (>2) <*> (<7)) [1..10]
```

This can be extended for multiple tests in the following slighty cryptic way:

```
import Control.Applicative

filter (and . ([ (>2) , (<7) , odd ] <*>) . pure) [1..10]
```

Of course after filtering you can map the list in any way you like.

**[Edit]**

If you want to show off, you can use Arrows as well:

```
import Control.Arrow

filter ((>2) &&& (<7) >>> uncurry (&&)) [1..10]
```

Comment: @Landei: wow! beautiful! I'm just learning applicative functors and this is a nice examples! thanks :)

Comment: @MarcoS: Actually this is a nice application for arrows as well, so I added this version as well. But for real world applications I would consider both Applicative and Arrow syntax a little bit over-the-top.

Comment: @Landei: Arrows are still beyond my knowledge, so I can't figure out what your last line of code means :) Anyway, thank you for pointing this out: one day I'll understand it!

Comment: @Landei: Arrows are still beyond my knowledge, so I can't figure out what your last line of code means :) Anyway, thank you for pointing this out: one day I'll understand it!

Comment: @MarcoS: A short but very intuitive introduction is http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_arrows

Answer (score 5):

`map` is used to map a function over a list. If you want to map a function only on the elements of a list that satisfy a condition, then you should probably use `filter`:

```
map (+2) $ filter (>0) [-10..120]
```

or if you have more conditions that must all hold

```
map (+2) $ filter (>0) $ filter (<100) [-10..120]
```

or equivalently

```
map (+2) $ filter (\x -> x>0 && x<100) [-10..120]
```